# $f$ integrable and $E_n=\{x\in X: f(x)>2n\}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have to calculate this 2 limits:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E_n}fd\mu \ \text{and} \ \lim_{n\to\infty}n\mu(E_n).$$

For the first one I do:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{E_n} f d\mu = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_X f\chi_{E_n}d\mu$$
Being $f\chi_{E_n}$ this sequence of function:
$$f\chi_{E_n}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
f &x\in E_n \\ 
0 & x\notin E_n
\end{matrix}\right.$$
By MCT, we have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_X f\chi_{E_n}d\mu=\int_X \left(\lim_{n\to \infty} f\chi_{E_n}\right)d\mu=\int_X 0d\mu=0$$

Now, calculating the second limit in the same way,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\mu(E_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_X\chi_{E_n}d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X n\chi_{E_n}d\mu$$
By MCT, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X n\chi_{E_n}d\mu=\int_X \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n\chi_{E_n}\right)d\mu$$

But this limit is an indeterminacy, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f \chi_{E_n} \geq 2n\chi_{E_n}$ we get  $\int_{E_n} f \geq \int_{E_n} 2n = 2n \mu (E_n)$ and $\int_{E_n} f  \to 0$ so $\lim n \mu(E_n)=0$.

Comment: $I_{E_n}$ is my $\chi _ {E_n}$?

Comment: @Irati .Yes . Same thing. $\chi$ comes from "characteristic function" and $I$ comes from "indicator function".

Comment: @User467 I have changed $I$ to $\chi$.